# mapping json into react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I think I have pretty easy question, but can't figure it out  by my own.
I am trying to map json object into table in react. Each key represent a column, and each value in the array is a row. How should I map it to achieve table structure like example below?

Json structure:

```js
{
  "code": [
    "111111",
    "222222",
    "333333"
  ],
  "name": [
    "nameA",
    "nameB",
    "nameB"
  ],
  "price": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
  ]
}
```

Structure of the table should be like:

| code | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | nameA | 1 |
| 222222 | nameB | 2 |
| 333333 | nameC | 3 |

Comment: You mean this https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#usetable ? Please include a [mcve] and show us some code that's not working, with debug logs, so we can help with a specific problem.

Comment: Provide your sample data that you want refactored

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think rob with his comment below exactly catch the point of my problem. I wasn't sure what would be best way to iterate json with this kind of structure in to the table.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work with your structure of js object or json
.
The problem is your structure should be changed to make it easier to iterate through.

```
    class Table extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                
            }
        }
        
        render() {
            var abc={
                "code": [
                    "111111",
                    "222222",
                    "333333"
                ],

                "name": [
                    "nameA",
                    "nameB",
                    "nameB"
                ],
                "price": [
                    1,
                    2,
                    3,
                ]
            }
            
            var trArr=[]
            var tb=function(){
                    abc.code.map(function(v,i){
                            trArr.push(
                                <tr key={i}>
                                    <td>{abc.code[i]}</td>
                                    <td>{abc.name[i]}</td>
                                    <td>{abc.price[i]}</td>
                                </tr>   
                            )
                    })
            
                    return(
                                    <table>
                            <thead> 
                            <tr><th>code</th><th>name</th><th>price</th></tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {trArr}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    )

            }()
        
            return (
            <div>
                {tb}
            </div>
            )
        }
}
```

Your structure should look more like this, so you can iterate/map over it as individual container records and not split up columns/values in separate arrays

```
[{
    "code": "11111",
    "name": "nameA",
    "price": 1
  },
  {
    "code": "22222",
    "name": "nameB",
    "price": 2
  },
  {
    "code": "33333",
    "name": "nameC",
    "price": 3
  }
 ]
```

Comment: The use of `abc.code.map()` is strange, `map` always creates a new array which you don't use. It would make more sense to use `abc.code.forEaxh()` instead. Or use `map` but then to create `trArr` (so without `push`)

Comment: @PeterB , agreed.
 This was not meant to be perfect code but rather to illustrate why the JSON structure is harder to iterate over, as the main question appeared to be more about the structure/schema .
What ever array iteration method is used in production is upto him/her, being old school in my own code, I tend to still use while loops. I also habitually use map except when im making an effort to be resource efficient .

Comment: thanks. This was exactly what I was trying to found out.